# Method for finding main logical operator given a formula

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing

**What I Want**

I need a method to get the index of the main operator in a logical formula.

So this is what i want for example:

Input: ~(BVC)V(AVE), where "~" is negation,"V" is disjunction.

Output: [~(BVC),V,(AVE)]

In general given a formula of propositional logic in the form "A OP B" as a String return the list [A,OP,B]

**My Idea**

Use Shunting-yard algo [(Wiki page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) convert input to postfix then get last character from the output,                                                                                                                                                                                in the original input. So in example above you have "V" as the main operator at index 6 so the output would be

```
{formula.substring(0,6),formula.charAt(6),formula.substring(7,11)}`
```

or more generally

```
{
    formula.substring(0,opIndex),
    lastElement,
    formula.substring(opIndex+1,formula.length())
}
```

**My Script**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Parser {

    /**
     * print String array
     */
    public static void printString(String[] s){
        System.out.print("{");
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
            System.out.print(s[i]);
            if(!(i==s.length-1)){
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return the index of c in list
     */
    public int indexOf(ArrayList<Character> list, Character c) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) == c) {
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return true if c is in list
     */
    public boolean contains(ArrayList<Character> list, Character c){
        for(Character i:list){
            if(i==c) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }





    /**
     * @param formula string to test
     * @return true if parentheses are validly placed
     */
    public boolean parenMatch(String formula){
        Stack parenStack= new Stack();
        for(int i=0;i<formula.length();i++){
            char token = formula.charAt(i);
            if(token == '('){
                parenStack.push(token);
            }
            else if(token == ')'){
                if(parenStack.isEmpty()){
                    return false;
                }
                parenStack.pop();
            }
        }
        if(parenStack.isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }



    /**
     * Shunting-yard
     * @param formula = A OP B
     * @return [A,OP,B]
     */
    public String[] parseFormula(String formula){

        if(!parenMatch(formula)){
            System.out.println("this formula:  '"+formula+ "' doesnt work");
            String[] result ={};
            return result;
        }

        ArrayList<Character> infix=new  ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i=0;i<formula.length();i++){
            infix.add(formula.charAt(i));
        }
        ArrayList<Character> removeFromInfix=new  ArrayList<Character>();//remove spaces from input
        for(Character c: infix){
            if(c==' ') removeFromInfix.add(c);
        }
        for(Character c: removeFromInfix){
            infix.remove(c);
        }


        char[] operators1={'<','>','V','&','~'};//highest order of precedence going from the right of array
        char[] alphabet1= {//V is not in list bc its an op
            'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
            'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
            'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
            'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B',
            'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
            'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
            'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'W',
            'X', 'Y', 'Z'
        };

        ArrayList<Character> operators=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Character> alphabet=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<operators1.length;i++){
            operators.add(operators1[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<alphabet1.length;i++){
            alphabet.add(alphabet1[i]);
        }



        Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<>();
        Queue<Character> inputTokens = new Queue<>();
        Queue<Character> output = new Queue<>();



        for(int i=0;i<infix.size();i++){
            inputTokens.enqueue(infix.get(i));
        }

        while((!inputTokens.isEmpty())){
            Character token = inputTokens.dequeue();

            //if its a character in alphabet
            if (contains(alphabet,token)) output.enqueue(token);

            //if its an operator
            else if (contains(operators,token)) {
                if (operatorStack.empty()) {
                    operatorStack.push(token);
                }
                else 
                {
                    Character topOperator =operatorStack.peek();
                    //while (precedence of op on top of operator stack > token) enqueue op onto result
                    while ((indexOf(operators,operatorStack.peek())) > (indexOf(operators,token)))
                    {
                        output.enqueue(topOperator);
                        topOperator = operatorStack.peek();
                        operatorStack.pop();

                        if (operatorStack.isEmpty()){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    operatorStack.push(token);
                }
            }

            //if its a "("
            else if (token == '(') {
                operatorStack.push(token);
            }
            else if (token == ')') {
                while (!(operatorStack.peek().equals('('))) {
                    output.enqueue((Character) operatorStack.peek());
                    operatorStack.pop();

                }
                operatorStack.pop();
            }

        }//end while



        while(!operatorStack.isEmpty()){
            output.enqueue(operatorStack.pop());
        }

        //get last element
        char lastElement=' ';
        for(char c: output){
            System.out.print(c);
            lastElement=c;
        }
        System.out.println();




        int opIndex=infix.indexOf(lastElement);
        String A=formula.substring(0,opIndex);
        String op=""+lastElement;
        String B=formula.substring(opIndex+1,formula.length());
        String[] result ={A,op,B};
        return result;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //~(BVC)V(AVE)
        Parser p =new Parser();
        printString(p.parseFormula("~(BVC)V(AVE)"));

    }
}
```

**Problem**

This is the output: {~(B,V,C)V(AVE)}.

So the problem w/ this method is when you have more than 1 of same op searching from left to right isnt going to give you the index you want.

Comment: try to keep a stack of all opened parenthesis (i.e. `(`), and pop every time you see a closing parenthesis (`)`). If the formula is valid, your operator should be the character following the last pop (when the stack becomes empty). If there are no parenthesis, it should be the first operator not at index 0.

Comment: Why a stack? A simple counter would be sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: You're right. I was confused with thinking that maybe there are several types (i.e. `(`, `[` etc) and the formula might not be valid. A counter should definitely suffice here.

Comment: So like:
iterate over string until number of left parentheses equals number of right parentheses and where that happens is the index of main operator


 `while(true) if (formula.charAt(index) == '(') countl++;
            else if (formula.charAt(index) == ')') countr++;
            index++;
            if((countl==countr) && (countl!=0)){
                break;
            }`